# Is there a limit on the amount that can be returned in an HTTP packet? Or is this WCF JSON limit?

Tags: json, wcf, http, serialization, limit

I am using a self-hosted (that is not in IIS) WCF data service that receives REST calls via GET and returns JSON.

I can return 3800 records, but when I go to 3900 it fails. It I get no error or warning events from WCF or .NET, the application continues to run perfectly for new requests. It just silently throws away the results and does not Serialize the data to JSON:

Here is the returned value for 3800 records:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1958039
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 14:28:39 GMT
```

{"count":3800,"results":[{"bbox":"18.57544760000000,- .......

This is the service contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    CatalogResults SearchBoxADO(string requestBox);
```

In the debugger, SearchBoxADO returns with no problems with 3900 records, but it is not being serialized, and no HTTP response is generated (Fiddler says no response to the request).

Comment: I frequently send json files of more than one Mo in get.

Answer (score 1):

Its the default settings by the WCF framework. In order to get larger data set back from the WCF REST Service you need to increase your readerQuotas as shown below both on client and server side:

```
<binding maxBufferPoolSize="655360" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
```

Also consider setting your maxItemsInObjectGraph to a large value as shown below:

```
<behavior>
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</behavior>
```

You can achieve the above via code as shown below:

Since you are configuring everything via code you can even define the readerQuotas with code as shown below:

```
Binding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;

var myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, myReaderQuotas, null);
```

If you are trying to get the data in a browser then i guess that should work if you are using any .NET app as client then you need to define the same readerQuotas as that are specified for the server

You can set the maxItemsInObjectGraph via code by adding the ServiceBehavior Attribute to your class as shown below:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647)]
public class Test
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    CatalogResults SearchBoxADO(string requestBox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be problem caused by some binding settings related to size of content like: maxBufferSize, maxBufferPoolSize or maxStringContentLength attribute from ReaderQuotas.

Try to check that settings

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many items are in each record being serialized, you may be running up against the default limit for the `maxItemsInObjectGraph` attribute of the `dataContractSerializer`.  [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph) discusses the property, but it does contain an error.  The default value is 65536 instead of Int32.MaxValue.